# how to reduce GWT war file size

Tags: gwt

i am using ExtGWT. my application has 5 modules. in war folder all five modules will be compiled and placed. but in every module **resources** folder is common. my intention is keeping resources folder common. so that the generated war size can be decreased. plz suggest me.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly, what you are asking for, but I guess, you don't want to upload everytime everything since the amount of data is quite large.

I do it this way:
- DON't create a war-file.
- simply use rsync to incrementally deploy the contents of the war-directory of your GWT-project like this:

> rsync -avc --compress --progress --delete --rsh='ssh' --cvs-exclude 
>   ./war 
>   root@serverip:/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/

So, only newer files gets uploaded to the server and remaining old files which are not used anymore gets deleted from the server.

Hoped this helped you.